# Python Installation Error python36.dll is missing

Tags: python

I'm having trouble installing python. Error python36.dll is missing. Already try importing python36.dll in folder but error still occur.

Sometime I succeed in installing but when I try to lunch the interpreter, I still encounter this error.

I try to uninstall. Unchecking the 'pip' while installation.

Comment: Please describe your problem more detailed! Include what you platform you have, what you have tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead.